# How can I distinctively count values I recieve from a union query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this query:

```
SELECT Pedido1 from mydb.atendimentos 
UNION ALL
SELECT Pedido2 from mydb.atendimentos
order by Pedido1 ASC
```

That gets me this result:
[What I get when executing the query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CbJwy.png)
Now what I it to deliver is:

```
Teste -> 3
Teste2 -> 1
```

Is there any way of doing this with a union?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called derived table.

http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/database-sql/derived-table-vs-subquery/

```
SELECT Pedido1, COUNT(*) AS PedidoCount
FROM 
(
    SELECT Pedido1 FROM mydb.atendimentos 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Pedido2 FROM mydb.atendimentos
) T
GROUP BY Pedido1
ORDER BY Pedido1
```